# Where was "An Elephant Sitting Still" filmed?

Tags: film-location, an-elephant-sitting-still

I’m curious about where the movie [*An Elephant Sitting Still*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Elephant_Sitting_Still) (2018) was made. Do you know in which Chinese city was the movie filmed?

Comment: Probably Shijiazhuang. You should be able to google some architectural features that have been represented in the film.

Answer (score 4):

According to the German site [Deutschlandfunk](https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/filmstart-an-elephant-sitting-still-erstlingswerk-und.691.de.html?dram:article_id=433524) the movie was filmed in the [Hebei province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebei).

> “Der Film ist in Hebei gedreht, in der Nachbarprovinz von Peking.”

In English that translates as:

> “The film is shot in Hebei, in the neighbouring province of Beijing.”

The movie is also mentioned in the [Wikipedia article for for Jingxing County](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingxing_County):

> “The 2018 film [*An Elephant Sitting Still*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Elephant_Sitting_Still) was filmed in Jingxing County.”